Is there a way to start using prisma migrations if I've been using prisma db push up until now?
Is there a way I can baseline my production db (mysql) using prisma and start using migrations if I've only been using prisma db push up until now, without losing all data/ having to reset the db?

I would replicate the production db, generate the migration files even if I lost all the data, replicate the production db again - and check if applying the migration files will destroy my db or not - that's how I would attempt it.

Absolutely. Prisma documentation goes through the whole process of baselining better than I could summarize, so do read the whole guide, but in short, you run:
npx prisma migrate diff \
--from-empty \
--to-schema-datamodel prisma/schema.prisma \
--script > prisma/migrations/0_init/migration.sql

This creates the baseline migration from your current schema. Then, you mark the migration as applied by running:
npx prisma migrate resolve --applied 0_init

After baselining, do not use db push command to save yourself from a world of hurt. Keep using migrations from this point on.
